# Access POS UEFI (Aptio) from linux

Tags: linux, uefi

I have a POS machine that uses the Aptio BIOS/UEFI. In there, there is an option called OS SELECTION which is set to linux/win7 as I use linux for that machine.

Is there a way to check this remotely or retrieve that information without having to reboot to uefi/bios?

I have used dmidecode but I can see "UEFI supported" only.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want the boot options, or the OS selection setting?

You can use [efibootmgr](https://linux.die.net/man/8/efibootmgr) to retrieve the current boot options on a UEFI system. I don't think there's an equivalent to this for BIOS-boot systems.

For general UEFI setup information like the OS selection setting, you'd need to use something like AMISCE, which is not really supposed to be generally available (although it's not too difficult to find a copy). I think you could technically use an older version of AMISCE (e.g one specifically compatible with AMIBIOS8) to retrieve setup information on a BIOS-boot system, but I'm not 100% confident about that.

Comment: Actually my issue is that I am using some POS that require OS Selection to be on Linux. As these are shipped and installed remotely, I'd like what are my options to set this somehow and check if on the already bought machines it has this option.